# Where can I get the permissions each Firefox extension requires?

Tags: firefox, permissions

When I install a Firefox extension, I am prompted a list of permissions required for the extension to work. I've accepted them.

Today, I've heard about [the spylish issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1472948): one of the extension (Stylish) seems to be a big spyware (hence I've removed it).

But I'm wondering if some other Firefox extensions could do the same. Therefore, I would like to see the permissions I've granted to each of the extensions I already have installed. Is there a way to do such check? I don't remember the permissions each of these required, and I'm willing to recheck them now.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link about Stylish.  I wasn't aware of that.  To your question, I'm not sure what permissions you're referring to.  I've never had any extension installation or usage ask for, or require, any special permissions.  Are you asking what permissions they inherit upon installation and/or how to restrict any permissions they inherit?

Comment: I mean [that kind of permissions request when you install an extension](https://xenos.reinom.com/perso/extension-permission.png) where it says "Extension will have access to your history, your tabs, your navigation activity,..." So I don't know how to see that list again once installed (and, if doable, how to restrict that list and deny some of the permissions, if doable)

Comment: That looks like a Ghostery message.  Does Ghostery display that when you install other extensions, or do some or all new extensions display a similar message?  I use Ghostery and have never seen that, but I assume it is just generic  information -- advising you of what any extension may be able to do because of the way the browser works.  Your only control is to choose to not install the extension, or uninstall it if the message comes after installation.

Comment: No, it's the message displayed when you install ghostery for the 1st time (you might try it yourself then). The same kind of messasge appears for any other extension (some with an empty list because they need nothing, and others with a big list). Indeed, it's a "accept or don't install" thing, but I'm now willing to recheck what I've accepted without having to uninstall and reinstall every extension (which would make me loose my preferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [I've asked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/asadotzler/status/1014956771855630336) and someone answered that these permissions are also displayed on the page of the extension itself (without requiring to reinstall it)

[image: Permissions are on the extension page]

Sorry I was dumb enough to not even notice this (and I admit, to haven't read the entire page at all)... I guess I'll need to open the page of every extension I've installed and see what permission each uses.

Comment: I was in the process of writing an answer suggesting that you could start Firefox from a command line with the `-p` parameter, add a new temporary profile (which would not contain any extensions), then add the extensions one at a time to that to see the messages.  Your solution is better.  Can you clarify which page you're referring to (it doesn't appear to be the extension's  "more information" page from the add-on list)?

Comment: It's on the extension page like https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/header-editor/ in the frame before the last one (Below "More info" which is below "add to collection" which is below "evaluate" on a Firefox Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to review all add-on permissions in Firefox Quantum is with the extension [Project Insight](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/project-insight/?src=search). It displays all permission of *enabled* add-ons:

[image]